# Tag pages are broken on mobile

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mobile

Right now, if you click on a low-traffic tag in the mobile view, you get this:

> You are on the FAQ tab.
>
> There are no frequently asked questions at the moment.
>
> Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

This page's mobile UI does not *have* any tabs, making the tag page fairly useless for most of our tags. And kinda frustratingly passive-aggressive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently dong a general review of the UI/UX of tags and tag navigation.

I've added this report to the things we need to address.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh good, so it's part of a process, not an oversight in a done-and-finished redesign.

Comment: It's certainly an oversight on our part, but there's no point fixing a page that may change substantially as part of a larger thing... :-)